# Hide button when the data is exist in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, yii2

I want to hide delete button when the course id already exist but I don't know how to do it since I'm not very familiar with angular js. Here is my code:

view page:

```html
<li ng-repeat="cl in value">
    <a ng-click="openModalEditCourseCategory('lg','',cl);" href="#"><b>{{cl.S_CODE}} {{cl.S_TITLE}}</b></a>
    <a ng-click="openCourseOutlinePdf(cl)" title="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Course Outline') ?>"><i
      class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>{{cl.COURSE_ID}} </a>
    <span ng-if="alreadyCheckedCo['i_' + cl.COURSE_ID] == 'checking'"
       class="label label-default">Checking...</span>
    <span ng-if="alreadyCheckedCo['i_' + cl.COURSE_ID] == 'opening'"
       class="label label-success">Opened</span>
    <span ng-if="alreadyCheckedCo['i_' + cl.COURSE_ID] == 'unavailable'"
       class="label label-warning">Course Outline Not Available</span>|
    <a ng-really-message="<?= Yii::t('app', "Are you sure to remove item?"); ?>"
       ng-really-click="removeCourseCategory(cl.COURSE_ID);"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <p ng-if="cl.S_SYNOPSIS">{{cl.S_SYNOPSIS}}</p>
    <p ng-if="!cl.S_SYNOPSIS"><?= Yii::t('app', "None") ?></p>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get if course_id == opening, the delete icon not appear and if course_id == unavailable,the delete icon is appear. If someone can help me,I'm very appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

your icon like this

```
<md-icon ng-hide="hideicon">delete</md-icon> //your icon
```

js

```
  if (course_id == opening) {
    $scope.hideicon = true;   // hide icon

   }
    else if (course_id == unavailable) {

    $scope.hideicon = false;  // show icon

 };
```